# SBS video not shown corectly in LG3D phone

Tags: android, video, 3d, lg

I converted a 2D>3D video using a popular software and in the option I chose SBS.
Conversion was ok but when I play the video in the LG 3D smartphone with Android it is shown like 2 pictures sidebyside in 3D and the player fails to converge the 2 pictures in one.

Does anyone have some suggestion? It seems that  is missing a flag to make the smartphone reading correctly the video or...

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problems were more than one
1-updated to latest SDK
2-modified the project target to specific LG add on library
3-Add in the manifest

```
<uses-library android:name="com.lge.real3d" android:required="true"/>
```

4-in the activity had to be set some code for Real3D you can find in the Real 3D specification guide provided by LG with the add-on

Be carefull to set the correct API, I suggest to use API 8 2.2.2 instead of API 10 and set in the manifest `android:minSdkVersion="8"`